# Open Storyboard on top of previous view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have created storyboard which I want to open on top of another view or in childView so that when I close or destroy this view of storyboard the earlier view on which the storyboard is opened remains the same.

When I run the following code:-

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
ViewController *detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"neolick"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:detailViewController];
```

First, the storyboard opens but I don't know whether it opens on top of previous view or it destroys the previous view & then open.
Second, the functions needed on that storyboard runs automatically which is as I want but how these things are working.

If anyone can help me understand the above code and its working.

NOTE: I cannot call the earlier view again in same state because of some reason.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are setting root view controller

it will not keep your back screen as it is what you want

If you want to keep current screen and show other screen on that

you have two approaches

1) Present ViewController 
2) Push View Controller

1) Present ViewController

for this you can present your screen on top of other screen which is visible

for example

```
- (IBAction)btnNextTapped:(id)sender {
     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
     ViewController *detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"neolick"];
     [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:true completion:nil]

 }
```

2) Push View Controller

For that you need `NavigationController`  and need to push your `ViewController` from  current visible screen

i.e

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
```

**EDIT**

as per discussion you need to find current top view controller then you should present it

Add this method  below your method

```
- (UIViewController*) topMostController
{
UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

while (topController.presentedViewController) {
    topController = topController.presentedViewController;
}

return topController;
}
```

And Replace this method with code

```
- (void)goToNewPage:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command 
    { 
       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil]; 
     ViewController *detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"neolick"]; 

      [[self topMostController] presentViewController:detailViewController animated:true completion:nil]; 
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...

I'm getting error "No visible @interface declares the selector presentViewController:animated:compilation"

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true]; when I use this code then i'm getting "property navigationcontroller not found on object of type" error

Comment: where are you putting this code ? , it also matters that from where you need to show that viewcotnroller ?

Comment: I'm using this code in sub-directory of the project. Do I have to import something for that?

Comment: sub-directory , what is it, let me know on which action you need to show `detailViewController`  like on tap of button or tap on tablecell ?

Comment: Project_name>Classes
AppDelegate, ViewController files are in above folder

Project_name>Plugins>com.example.myClass>customClass>
MyCustomClass file is in above folder

Now the code i'm using in MyCustomClass file.
This file function get triggered on click of a button.

Comment: ok on trigger of button some thing like  -> `- (IBAction)btnNextTapped:(id)sender` add that code

Comment: Still showing the same error. And the function I have is this 
- (void)goToNewPage:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149595/discussion-between-mike-alter-and-ajay).

Comment: @ajay I have updated Answer , Pls check it if worked then accept answer  by Right check mark